# Error on Goggle Colab: NMS time limit 2.100s

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolov8

While I was training Yolov8 model on 50 epoch, I got the following error NMS time limit 2.100s exceeded

What does it mean and how to solve it ?

The model is still training but it is giving this error while performing the epoch

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase or decrise the batch during training to find the right batch for your machine resource, I had the same problem and I set the batch = 32 and it worked for me.